# Preserve Aspect ratio on internet explorer with svg image

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, aspect-ratio, css

I have an svgz image called image.scgz with specified width and height.

I would like to make a thumb image of it of width 120px and keeping aspect ratio.

On chrome I just have to write `<img src="image.svgz" style="width:120px;" />`

However it does not work on ie 9 & 10:

- First of all I have to write `<img src="image.svgz" style="max-width:120px;" />` to scale the width and I do not understand the logic.
- Secondly the aspect ratio is not kept

I have seen solution using `preserveAspectRatio` attribute of the balise svg but i would like to not modified my image files.

Comment: What does image.svgz look like? Does it have a viewBox attribute? Does it have defined width and height?

Comment: It does not have viewBox defined but it has width and height. It is generated by inkspace.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to use an SVG `<image>` element rather than an HTML `<img>`  element as an SVG `<image>` element can take preserveAspectRatio and viewBox attributes that an html `<img>` element does not support.

Comment: I have tried but the preserveAspectRatio seems ignored. Probably because the viewbox is not defined on my svg image (just width and height property are filled)

Comment: You must use an SVG image rather than an HML img.